# Look for the group members $\left ( (\mathbb Z/24\mathbb Z)^*,\underset{24}{\odot} \right )$ and calculate their orders.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, order-theory, residue-calculus

> Look for the group members $\left ( (\mathbb Z/24\mathbb Z)^*,\underset{24}{\odot} \right )$ and calculate their orders.

The elements are $\overline1,\overline2,\ldots,\overline{23}$.

Have the orders, how do I calculate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The elements are *not* $1,2,\ldots,23$, rather they are $1,5,7,11,13,17,19,23$. Then note $1^2=5^2=7^2=11^2=1\mod 24$.

In fact, $\Bbb Z/24\Bbb Z\simeq \Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z/8\Bbb Z$ whence $\Bbb Z/24\Bbb Z^\times \simeq \Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z^\times\times \Bbb Z/8\Bbb Z^\times\simeq \Bbb Z/2 \Bbb Z^3$. Remember that if $n\geqslant 2$, $(\Bbb Z/2^n\Bbb Z)^\times\simeq \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z/ 2^{n-2}\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Really? 
I do not understand why only cousins​​?

Comment: The notation $A^\ast$ stands for the invertible elements of the ring, which are those coprime to $24$.

Comment: Wow, how nice, is to prove that $24 \mid p^2-1$ with p being prime? I'll try.

Comment: Then the notation $\left ( (\mathbb{Z}/24\mathbb{Z})^*,\underset{24}{ \odot} \right )$ does not mean the elements of the set $(\mathbb{Z}/24\mathbb{Z})$, excluding the $0$?

Comment: @marcelolpjunior The asterisk usually means "units".

Comment: Thank you, I will try some stuff to try to better understand these notations, it was still a bit complicated for me to understand how this would be "unity".